# explicit cast calling constructor?

Tags: java, oop, casting, static

I have two classes `A` and `B`.

**Question**: Why does the line `System.out.println(b.x)` print 23 as a result?

I would agree for 22 as a result because the constructor of `A` and the constructor of `B` each increment the `static int y` by 1.

```
public class A {
   public long x = 0;
   public static int y = 20;

   public A(float x) {
      this((int) x );
      A.y++;
   }

   public A(int x) {
      this.x = x;
   }

   public int f(double d) {
      return 1;
   }

   public int f(long l) {
      return 2;
   }
}

public class B extends A {
   public int x = 1;

   public B() {
      this(42);
      B.y++;
   }

   public B(int x) {
      super(x + 0.f);
      this.x += this.x;
   }

   public int f(long l) {
      return 3;
   }

   public int f(float f) {
      return 4;
   }
}


public class M {
   public static void main(String[] args) {

   A a = new A(10f);
   System.out.println(a.x);

   System.out.println(A.y);

   B b = new B();
   System.out.println(((A b).x); // 23
}
```

Comment: is this not throwing compilation error.

Comment: @jublikon you mean that `b.y` is 23? not `b.x`, right?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

`b.y` is `23` because the `B` constructor calls also the `A` constructor, using `super(x + 0.f);`.

Therefore `y` is incremented 3 times, 1 time in `A a = new A(10f);` and 2 times in `B b = new B();`

Answer (score 1):

First I believe you wanted to write this line of code as
  System.out.println(((A b).y); // 23

**rather than**

System.out.println(((A b).x); // 23

So my explanation is:

In the M class series of calls are happening which is making your b.y print 23

**20 -> 21**

1. A's constructor is called by passing the float value.
   Overloaded A constructor increments static y by 1.

[image: 1st image]

**21->22**

2. B's empty arguments constructor is called  B b = new B(),
   which initializes x hence B's integer constructor is called.

   [image: Image 2]

[image]

Which calls A's constructor with float parameter.

[image: 1st image]

**22-23**
3. After completing the above call the control returns to default overloaded constructor with empty parameters.

[image]